# Datagrid in Datagrid Row Template

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

Can't bind collection property to data grid row template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailsTemplate" DataType="{x:Type summons:IndividualDefendantSearchViewModel}">

            <controls:ExtendedDataGrid
                x:Name="RowDetails"
                CanUserSortColumns="True"
                ContentWidth="910"
                DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Parent, Path=DataContext.GroupedSearchResults}"
                Focusable="False"
                HeadersVisibility="None"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults}"
                ShowRowSelection="False">

                <controls:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>             
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        Width="*"
                        Binding="{Binding Name}"
                        Header="{localization:LanguageBinding ResourceKey=Name}" />
                </controls:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
            </controls:ExtendedDataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

My Data Template

```
public class SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResult : CheckedListItem<SearchResult>
{

    public string Name
        => $"{Item.FirstName} {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Insertion) ? "" : Item.Insertion + " ")}{Item.LastName}";


}

public class GroupedSelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResult: EnhancedBindableBase
{

    public DateTime? SearchDate { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResult>
        _selectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults;


    public ObservableCollection<SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResult>
        SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults {
        get { return _selectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults, value); }
    }

}
```

My property:

```
public ObservableCollection<GroupedSelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResult> GroupedSearchResults
    {
        get { return _groupedSearchResults; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _groupedSearchResults, value); }
    }
```

Main DataGrid ItemSource is

```
ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedSearchResults}"
```

I can see SearchDate bound to main rows, but RowDataTemplate is empty string... What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a property named 'SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults' in your IndividualDefendantSearchViewModel?

Comment: No, SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults is a property of GroupedSearchResults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bind the `DataContext` to `{Binding ElementName=Parent, Path=DataContext.GroupedSearchResults}`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailsTemplate">
    <controls:ExtendedDataGrid
                x:Name="RowDetails"
                CanUserSortColumns="True"
                ContentWidth="910"
                Focusable="False"
                HeadersVisibility="None"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults}"
                ShowRowSelection="False">

        <controls:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                        Width="*"
                        Binding="{Binding Name}"
                        Header="{localization:LanguageBinding ResourceKey=Name}" />
        </controls:ExtendedDataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:ExtendedDataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you:)

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to upvote helpful answers :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0):

The type of the DataContext of your DataTemplate is `IndividualDefendantSearchViewModel`. So your ItemsSource binding points to `IndividualDefendantSearchViewModel.SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults`, right?

You have to bind to another DataContext where the `SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults` property is located.
You can do this with the following:

```
{Binding DataContext.SelectableIndividualDefendantSearchResults, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}
```

The UserControl holds the DataContext with the target property and you need to adapt it for your purpose (if it's different from UserControl).

Addition:

mm8 is right. do not bind to the DataContext of your DataGrid, there is no need.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was only in {Binding ElementName=Parent, Path=DataContext.GroupedSearchResults}: